# SSOCircle URL List

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I was able to get my metadata imported into SSOCircle for my sample application.  From there I can get my [Spring-based application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html) running.  However, I am trying to write this in a different language and I don't see where I am supposed to post the **Authn Request** to in my other applications.

I have a .NET app using [ComponentPro](http://www.componentpro.com/saml.net/) that I am currently working in and I am at the point of submitting the `AuthnRequest` but just can't figure out where to send it.  In the Spring application (as linked) I do not see the URL resolution and am trying to figure out where to debug to find the URL building.

Does anyone have a complete URL list for [SSOCircle](http://www.ssocircle.com) and the methods (POST/PUT/etc.) to use for sending data?

Comment: Of course, suddenly I change my language in Google and I find http://www.ssocircle.com/en/ssocircle-how-to/public-idp-configuration/ - I'll post back if that works.

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is here:
http://www.ssocircle.com/en/ssocircle-how-to/public-idp-configuration/.

Once I found that I was able to get everything posted and set.  Needed to correct some signature issues, but after that all was happy.